# Replace internal links using regex, but not if they are dynamic, i.e. contains a php echo

Tags: php, regex

I am going through a project and replacing internal links to go through a url function. I have created a bit of regex which does what I need, however I don't want it to do anything with dynamic links, as I'm going to go through and do them manually.

My regex is:

```
(href|src)=(?:'|")\/(?!http)(.+?)(?:'|")
```

My replace is:

```
$1="<?php echo url('$2'); ?>"
```

This works fine for:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/public/css/print.css' media="print"/>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://example.com/public/css/print.css' media="print"/>
```

I want it to ignore the following though:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/public/css/print<?php echo 1; ?>.css' media="print"/>
```

Bonus points if someone can provide a seperate regex and replace which takes the echo and places it in a string concatination of the url function! Something along the lines of

```
$1="<?php echo url('$2' . $3 . '$4'); ?>"
```

Comment: To do that, use `DOMDocument` and not a regex. I don't understand your "bonus" question.

Answer (score 0):

`(?:'|")\/(?!http)([^<]+?)(?:'|")`

will probably be good enough for the first part. Ie, replace the . with [^<] to match only strings that don't contain an opening angle bracket.

This might work ok for the second part

`(?:'|")\/(?!http)([^<]+?)(<\?php[^>]*?>)?([^<]+?)(?:'|")`

Answer (score 0):

I would have use this one:

```
(href|src)=(?:'|")\/(?!http)((?!php).)+?(?:'|")
```

---

explanation:

```
    1st Capturing group (href|src)
        1st Alternative: href
            href matches the characters href literally (case insensitive)
        2nd Alternative: src
            src matches the characters src literally (case insensitive)
    = matches the character = literally
    (?:'|") Non-capturing group
        1st Alternative: '
            ' matches the character ' literally
        2nd Alternative: "
            " matches the characters " literally
    \/ matches the character / literally
    (?!http) Negative Lookahead - Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below
        http matches the characters http literally (case insensitive)
    2nd Capturing group ((?!php).)+?
        Quantifier: +? Between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
        Note: A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data
        (?!php) Negative Lookahead - Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below
            php matches the characters php literally (case insensitive)
        . matches any character (except newline)
    (?:'|") Non-capturing group
        1st Alternative: '
            ' matches the character ' literally
        2nd Alternative: "
            " matches the characters "
```